# How to read the excel file from cloud or server?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following code:

```
     Wbnwsheet = pd.read_excel(r"C:/Users/SHI/ingrendient.xlsm",
                   sheetname="Step1", sep='\t')
```

this code is direct read from my desktop, how about if I want read the excel file from cloud or server that the path are start with" \ingredient\....\  ?

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the documentation of Pandas.read_excel [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.read_excel.html), you will notice that io parameter also accepts the follow parameters

1. http urls
2. ftp url

> Parameters:
>
> io : string, path object (pathlib.Path or py._path.local.LocalPath),
>
> file-like object, pandas ExcelFile, or xlrd workbook. The string could be a URL. Valid URL schemes include http, ftp, s3, and file. For
>   file URLs, a host is expected. For instance, a local file could be
>   file://localhost/path/to/workbook.xlsx

hence, you could use `pd.read_excel()` in the following way to achieve your purpose.

```
pd.read_excel('http://yourwebsite.com/path_to_excel_doc/excel_doc.xlsm')
```

Cheers!